# Broke apt-get update configuration

Tags: apt, updates

I'm absolutely new with Linux (Ubuntu 19.10) and I've already misconfigured something.

When I execute '`sudo apt-get update`' I get the following message

```
Hit:1 ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                      
Hit:3 es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                             
Hit:4 ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                   
Hit:5 es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                     
Hit:6 es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                   
Hit:7 apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt eoan-pgdg InRelease                                    
Ign:8 ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu eoan InRelease                      
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu eoan Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]  
Hit:10 download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                             
E: The repository 'ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

And of course the app 'Software & Update' tells me that there's was an error and that I should check the internet connection.

I've been told that I shouldn't be using such a new linux release for support reasons and possible bugs. But this was working up until a few hours ago, I tried fixing something and did this with some command I don't even remember.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not bugs. You've added repositories that do not exist. Remove them, and things will get muy bueno.

Comment: Thank you, reading through a thousand posts I came to that conclusion myself, but was just afraid that I'd might delete something important. Already did it and every thing is sehr gut ineed.

Comment: I realize you've solved it, but if you were to open http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu in a browser, navigate to dists/ folder you can quickly see what it supports, ie. support was last provided for bionic (18.04), three releases before your eoan.  Good job solving it yourself though !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

Log in and enter "history | less".

Scroll up and down using the arrow keys. You should be able to find those earlier commands that caused the problem.

If you were also root, you can do the same there.

Mike G.

Comment: I've already solved it with mikewhatever's comment. But that command will be very useful to me in the future, no doubt. Thank you.